# Where to place the front-end javascript files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, express-generator

I am developing an [express](http://expressjs.com/) based web application and I started following the  application skeleton built by [express-generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html).

Next, I added to my project [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) to bundle the client side assets.

Now I am not sure where to place the front-end javascript files, if in a `/src`  or `/app` folder?

In truth, I am in a dilemma between, `app.js`, `/lib`, `/src` and `/app` folders.

1. According to [express-generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html), it creates an `app.js` file as the main entry and thus it looks a little bit strange to have an `app` folder with same name of the entry point `app.js`.
2. [webpack usage manual](https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage.html) suggests a `/src` folder to place javascript files. But I think `/src` should not be exclusively for front-end javascripts and on the other hand, I would not like to mix both server and front-end javascript files in same folder.
3. Moreover, the Accepted Answer to the question [Folder structure for a Node.js project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5193206/1140754), contradicts the previous point because it states:

> /src contains all your server-side specific CoffeeScript files

So, I think that maybe `/src` is not the better option to place front-end javscript files and according to the Accepted answer to the question [Node.js project naming conventions for files & folders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20885809/1140754) I would follow the proposed structure:

```
  /app - front-end javascript files
  /bin - helper scripts
  /lib - back-end express files
```

But is it ok to have a folder `/app` and a file `app.js` with same name? Furthermore, `/app` is related with front-end and `app.js` with back-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to just rename your main file from `app.js` to `index.js` and keep the structure proposed in [Node.js project naming conventions for files & folders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20885809/1140754):

```
  /app - front-end javascript files
  /bin - helper scripts
  /lib - back-end express files
```

Thus, there is no more misleading between `/app` folder related to front-end and the `index.js`, which is the back-end entry point.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a "required" structure for web apps, as Abdellah stated, it's usually best to just go with what you and your colleagues are comfortable with. However, because Node.js has a built in framework, you should *probably* use that. The move that makes the most sense to me is to rename the `app.js` file, and use the structure you stated.

Answer (score 0):

I think `public` folder is rather [common in web projects](https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter).

Since it's the destination of the generated `bundle`, i think you can name it more explicitly `webApp` or whatever you want. I think it's your call and there is no rigid/best practice here. Go with something you and your team are comfortable with.

Comment: `/public`is the the destination for `bundle.js`which aggregates all assets packed  by `webpack`.