# File and directory naming rules for nodejs project

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am building a nodejs project by using typescript. In this project, I want add some file/directory naming rules. Such as, file/directory name should be in sneak-case.

Is there any way that I can apply any restrictions on the file names like we give coding convention rules by tslint?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js project naming conventions for files & folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927298/node-js-project-naming-conventions-for-files-folders)

Comment: @Billa: The question you mention is different from my question. In that question, naming conventions are discussed. My question is that, I want to apply restriction on file names according to naming conventions that I choose.